# Java - Parameter Passing Confusion

Tags: java, object, parameters, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

"Java is `pass-by-value`"
-[Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#8.4.1)
However, there are things that confuses me. Please take a glimpse of my example

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuilder myBuilder = new StringBuilder("Michael");

        editString(myBuilder);

        System.out.println(myBuilder);

    }

    public static void editString(StringBuilder x){
        x.append(" Ardan");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Michael Ardan
```

And this example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int myInt = 10;

        editInt(myInt);

        System.out.println(myInt);

    }

    public static void editInt(int x){
        x ++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
10
```

I tried reading other articles and it all says that Java is always `pass-by-value`. I've done some test scenario. Comparing both example to each other made me think that Java's Objects are `pass-by-reference` and primitive types are `pass-by-value`. However, if you tried to replace the `int` primitive type into `Integer` Object, the result would be the same. I would love if somebody explain these two examples here.

Comment: In Java Objects are always pass-by-reference whereas variables are pass-by-value. Also Strings are immutable objects.

Comment: @H-Patel every single article, even JLS says that Java is strictly pass-by-value regardless of datatype.

Comment: @Thilo It was a good question. I also tried reading the answers and made my scenarios. I was actually asking about what's happening behind my examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, Java *is* pass-by-value.

However, what gets passed by value is a "pointer" to an object. So you will be able to access and modify the state of that object from inside the called method (and those changes are visible to everyone else who has a "pointer" to the same object).

Pass-by-reference would mean that you can change where the variable on the calling side points to. That you cannot do in Java.

For example

```
  public static void editString(StringBuilder x){
     x = new StringBuilder("Foo");
  }
```

has no effect outside of the method. In pass-by-reference, you would actually be assigning that new StringBuilder back into the calling method variable.

Answer (score -2):

you are right , java object always pass-by-reference, but,you can see the source code of wrapper class like 'Integer','String','Short' and so on.they are 'value' are definded as final .it can not be changed .so ,the question 'if you tried to replace the int primitive type into Integer Object, the result would be the same.' which related with it.when you replace with Integer Object and change the value in you method. the Object changes. so, you can see the result.